# returning a "template class object" in a function

Tags: c++, function, templates

I have a template class like this

```
//Matrix.h
template <class T = double>
class Matrix
{
    //some constructors variables and ...
};
```

defined in a file called **Matrix.h** now how can I return an object from this class in other file say **assemble.h** something like:

```
//assemble.h
#include "Matrix.h"
Matrix<T> assemble(Matrix<T> KG,int node)
{
    //some other codes
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> [Matrix template] defined in a file called Matrix.h now how can I
>   return an object from this class in other file say assemble.h

`Matrix` is not a class in itself. It's a template; view it as a means to **create classes**, e.g. `Matrix<int>`, `Matrix<std::string>`, `Matrix<double>` or `Matrix<MyClass>`.

Therefore, the question is: Do you want your `assemble` function to work with *any* matrix class or do you want it to work one *particular* matrix class?

In the former case, you must templatise the function as well (which means that, similar to what happened above, you no longer have a function but a function-creation mechanism):

```
template <class ContentType>
Matrix<ContentType> assemble(Matrix<ContentType> KG, int node)
{
    // ...
}
```

(I've named the template parameter `ContentType` in this example, just so that you can see it does not have to be the same name as the template parameter in `Matrix`.)

In the latter case, you must specify the concrete class:

```
Matrix<int> assemble(Matrix<int> KG, int node)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

By the way, you may want to pass your matrix objects by const reference, especially in the absence of C++11 move features.

Answer (score 1):

`assemble` needs to be a template function as well :

```
template<typename T>
Matrix<T> assemble(Matrix<T> KG,int node)
{
    Matrix<T> m;
    //some other codes
    return m;
}
```

**Note:**

- You should declare it in one of your namespaces, not in the global one.
- Consider passing `KG` as a reference-to-const, instead than by value